# They Counted Votes

Tags: word-meaning

I have a question about the usage of the verb "*count*".  I have the following two sentences:

> 1. They ***counted*** the votes.
> 2. They ***counted*** 570 votes.

Examples similar to both sentences could be found on the web. Sentence 1 seems to denote the processing of finding out how many votes there were.  Sentence 2 seems to denote the result of such a process.  But dictionaries only have definitions for the usage in sentence 1.  The usage in sentence 2 could not be found in dictionaries.  Could it be that sentence 2 is non-standard?  Or, is it that dictionaries are missing a definition for the usage in sentence 2?

Comment: 570 is a quasi-adjectival determiner. They counted votes. They counted all votes. They counted some votes. They counted 10 votes.

Answer (score 1):

Both usages are common.

I don't know what dictionary you're using. Perhaps the definition is poorly worded, or perhaps you're splitting it too finely. Writing dictionary definitions that truly capture the meaning of a word is a fine art.

Many verbs that take an object can take either the "raw materials" or the "result". "I cooked pasta, cheese, and meat" versus "I cooked lasagna". "I wrote words on the paper" versus "I wrote a book". "The doctor cured my uncle's cancer" versus "The doctor cured my uncle and he is now perfectly healthy". Etc.

So yes, "I counted the puppies and found that there were ten of them", and "I counted ten puppies". Both are perfectly valid and common.

Comment: I want a puppy now. Maybe not ten of them.

Answer (score 0):

To say "They counted 570 votes" is to say that a total of 570 votes (or ballots) were processed. To refer to the results one might say "They counted 570 votes, 400 Republican and 170 Democrat." or "They counted 400 votes for the incumbent, and 170 for the challenger."

A bit closer to your usage might be a vote counter reporting that, "My colleague and I reached different totals for the incumbent. He counted 330 votes, but I only counted 320." In this case, "for the incumbent" is implied.

In other words, your second usage is not, in my experience, common.